# О произношении некоторых слов (стена, стол, змея)

Tags: орфография, орфоэпия, мягкий-знак

Начальный согласный смягчается в слове ***стена***, но произносится твердо в словах ***стол*** и ***змея***, мягкий знак же не пишется во всех примерах.

Носители языка в устной речи делают выбор интуитивно, но как такое произношение осваивают люди, изучающие **русский язык как иностранный**?

Возможны ли здесь трудности, как бы вы объяснили им эту тему (смягчение некоторых согласных перед другими согласными, а также правила обозначение такого произношения на письме)?

Спасибо.

**ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ МАТЕРИАЛ**

1. Я отчасти имею представление о  **физиологии  этих звуков**, они называются **зубными**. Это касается пяти звуков: Т/Д, Д/З и Н. Место образования у них одинаковое – кончик языка упирается **в основание передних зубов**, а способ произношения разный: Т/Д – смычные, З/С – щелевые (фрикативные). В одном случае звук получается при размыкании смычки, а в другом воздух проходит через щель и возникает трение.

Когда произносится **мягкий звук**, то **спинка языка** дополнительно поднимается к небу, такие звуки называются **двухфокусными.**

Для сравнения в английском языке  при произношении  этих звуков кончик языка смещается к небу,  а это звучит иначе, поэтому ТС /ДЗ несложно отличить от русского варианта.

2. Понятно, что в сочетании ТС звук Т легко переходит в С: кончик и спинка языка остаются на месте на месте, поэтому смягчение первого звука  Т **гораздо менее затратное**, чем произношение твердого: *степь, стена,  стихи.*

А вот в английском варианте мягких Т и С нет: кончик языка  смещен, спинку языка труднее поднять (так мне кажется).

3. Мягкие варианты русских звуков Т/Д, Д/З и Н интересны тем, что фактически смысловой является **пара звуков** (ст и сьть) – они несамостоятельные, хотя мы именно так считаем. Чтобы расширить их возможности, надо бы убрать смягчение первого звука, сделать их **независимыми**.

И такую тенденцию, как я думаю, мы наблюдаем в паре НС (звук Н – боковой сонорный, но тоже зубный). Сравнить: пансионат и пенсия, в первом слове нет смягчения Н перед мягким С, как во втором.

Также слово  «ветви» раньше произносилось, вероятно, со смягчением Т перед В, но сейчас твердое произношение (В – губно-зубный звук).

4. Кстати, в слове «***стенд***» гласный произносится твердо (как Э), поэтому там нет смягчения. В слове ***змея*** звук М – губный, к группе зубных не имеет отношения. Соответственно,  разные звуки не влияют друг на друга. В паре ***брось –  бросьте*** мы обозначаем не мягкость, а повелительное наклонение.
5. И вот что интересно. У носителей языка произношение **интуитивное**, а как учатся  всему этому иностранцы, **умеют** ли они смягчать зубные звуки, трудно ли им это сделать?  Как им объясняют, что это касается определенных звуков, а не всех.  Отражается ли это в речи в виде акцента?

Хотелось бы эту тему лучше узнать именно **в практическом плане**. Нужно ли  при изучении произношения подробно знать фонетику или это необязательно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Произношение носителей языка подчиняется физиологической простоте. Если в сочетании, записываемом как -ст-, нет смягчения т->ть (перед смягчающим гласным или непосредственно - что записывается мягким знаком), то твердо произносится и предшествущий -с-. И наоборот, если -т- в этом сочетании требует смягчения, то оно распространяется на предшествующий -с-. По всей видимости, к произношению -с- и -т- положение языка приспособлено одинаково хорошо, а для пары -сь- и -ть- оптимальное положение отличается настолько, что переключаться на него "неудобно". В результате для произношения -ть- положение языка выбирается общим для обоих согласных звуков, и реально сочетаются только звуки с условной записью -**ст**- и -**сьть**-, но нет звука с фонетической записью -сть-, а -сьт- практически не встречается внутри слов (только на стыках или в редких сложных словах). Отсюда простейшее правило для иноязычных:

> -**ст**- перед
> смягчающей гласной и -**сть**- читаются как "**сьть**".

Что касается учебной записи для чтения, то для обозначения смягчения можно добавлять апостроф, но правило кажется достаточным и без него. Любопытно, найдутся ли исключения. Нужно, конечно, учитывать, что в ряде слов "смягчающие" гласные не смягчают ("стенд" и др.).

На произвольные сочетания согласных этот подход не распространяется, но что-то похожее имеет место в случае -**сд**- и -**зд**- (здесь/здорово/сделать/сдобрить... - зд/зьдь).

Comment: Спасибо вам за ваше мнение, я разберусь чуть позже и отвечу вам.

Comment: Alex_ander, еще раз спасибо за ответ, я кое-то написала в дополнительном материале (посмотрите, пожалуйста).  А вы общались с англичанами (или с представителями других национальностей), есть ли у вас какая-то информация о том, как они изучают русское произношение?